# Parallel for loop running out of bounds java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm having problems with a for loop in my university project. My loop is trying to read and store values from the kb and store in the array. I have created the max value for my array, but when I'm getting to the final input, the loop is running out of bounds. I know it is probably something simple, but cannot find the solution from previous questions answered. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    public void getAu() {
    final int max = 7;
    String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" +
            "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    int[] totalAu = new int[max];

    for (int index = 0; index <= max; index++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter day of the week: ");
        days [index] = kb.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter Au: " );
        totalAu [index] = kb.nextInt();
        
     }//for
```

Comment: Think about the values `index` will take as your for loop runs, and think about the valid indexes of a 7 element array.

Comment: Your array only has 6 elements. Look at `"Friday" + "Saturday"`, that concatenates it to a single string. Replace the `+` with a `,`. Also, in your loop, the condition should be `index < max`

Answer (score 0):

An array that has N elements in it has indexes between 0 and N-1. You should continue the loop as long as `index < max`, not `index <= max`:

```
for (int index = 0; index < max; index++) {
    // Here --------------^
```

Comment: Thanks guys the concatenation and = were the issues that were causing the loop to fail. Much appreciate the help.